# Toggler icon does not working on adjusting the navbar width

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a navigation bar with height changed to 2.5rem due to which the toggler is not displaying any menu items. If I change is back to default it works fine. Right now the icon appears as below -
[image: Hamburger Icon]
Please help me fix this.

Below is my code -

HTML -

```
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg " id="header-bar">
    <button class="navbar-dark navbar-toggler" type="button" data- 
  toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria- 
   controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false"
            aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">ITEM1 <span class="sr-only"> 
     (current)</span></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">ITEM2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">ITEM3</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">ITEM4</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">ITEM5</a>
            </li>
            
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

CSS -

```
 *{
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 }
 body {
 font-family: sans-serif;
 font-size: 16px;
 }
 nav {
 background:#001a33;
 height: 2.5rem;
 }  
 .navbar-nav .nav-link{
 color: white;
 }
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: add your bootstrap css and js library link in working example

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script 
    src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"> 
    </script>

Answer (score 0):

Adding py-0 class to the nav tag solves the problem (to adjust height of the navbar). Changing height attribute messes with the hamburger content alignment-that has to be removed.